# Stack Exchange search pagination bug

Tags: bug, search, stackexchange.com, pagination

EEK! or possibly even EEEEEk!

I think I've found a minor bug in the pagination of search results on [Stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/). Search results seem to consistently return 10 pages, even if fewer than 10 pages are actually returned.

Steps to recreate:

1. Search for a term like "bug" on https://stackexchange.com/
2. Scroll to the bottom of the search results, and see the pagination links numbered 1-10
3. Click on link number 10
4. You'll see that "bug" really returns 7 pages...

I'm also thinking that the search results look a little limited, on [Meta Stackoverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) alone I'm seeing 682 pages for [[bug]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug) and 271 pages for ["bug"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22bug%22)... So the search results may be hitting a maximum number of pages/results which seems a little odd.

Comment: Weird... upon clicking on the 10th page I seem to get 69 results... Is someone trying to say something?

Comment: @DoktoroReichard yes 69 results over 7 pages, scroll to the bottom and look at the pagination links again.

Comment: ...I was trying to give a reference but oh well... Yes I saw that, also tried to search in google, no noticeable error found

Comment: The network search is just a Google site search, so I imagine it's an issue with that (although whether or not anything can be done about it is hard to say).

Comment: You [see this on Google as well](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=07789789789&safe=active) if you search for something uncommon. The message says *In order to show you the most relevant results, we have omitted some entries very similar to the x already displayed.*, maybe it's the same thing on SE, but without the custom error message.

Comment: @JMK I think it may have to do with Google's Safe Search. Searching your numbers [without the safe search filter](https://www.google.com/#q=07789789789&start=0) returns 3 actual pages rather than 2.